Leetcode - Find the student that will replace the chalk
I tried the problem Find the Student that Will Replace the Chalk on LeetCode.

There are n students in a class numbered from 0 to n - 1. The teacher will give each student a problem starting with the student number 0, then the student number 1, and so on until the teacher reaches the student number n - 1. After that, the teacher will restart the process, starting with the student number 0 again.
You are given a 0-indexed integer array chalk and an integer k. There are initially k pieces of chalk. When the student number i is given a problem to solve, they will use chalk[i] pieces of chalk to solve that problem. However, if the current number of chalk pieces is strictly less than chalk[i], then the student number i will be asked to replace the chalk.
Return the index of the student that will replace the chalk pieces.

I thought my solution should work but there is on test case where it doesn't work and I don't understand why.
Here is the test case.
And here is my code:
class Solution {
    public int chalkReplacer(int[] chalk, int k) {
        return getChalkReplacer(chalk, k);
    }
    public int getChalkReplacer(int[] chalk, int remaining_chalk){
        int chalk_sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<chalk.length; i++){
            chalk_sum += chalk[i];
            if(remaining_chalk - chalk_sum <= 0 || chalk[i] > remaining_chalk){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return getChalkReplacer(chalk, remaining_chalk % chalk_sum);
    }
}


Welcome to SO! Please read [ask]. Details relevant to your problem should be included in the question itself, not hyperlinked to a coding competition site. Also, Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

remaining_chalk % chalk_sum looks wrong on principle - why are you performing a modulo operation (which gives you the remainder of a division)?

@UnholySheep It is correct for finding the chalk remaining after the maximum number of full passes through the n students.

Note that the problem statement asks for when the amount of remaining chalk is strictly less than the chalk that student i requires.

if the current number of chalk pieces is strictly less than chalk[i], then the student number i will be asked to replace the chalk

The issue is thus with the if statement here.
if(remaining_chalk - chalk_sum <= 0 || chalk[i] > remaining_chalk)

chalk[i] > remaining_chalk is redundant and should be omitted. It is fine for remaining_chalk to be equal to chalk_sum, so <= should be changed to <.
if (remaining_chalk - chalk_sum < 0)

This can be rearranged to simply:
if (remaining_chalk < chalk_sum)


class Solution {
public:
    int chalkReplacer(vector<int>& chalk, int k) {
        long long chalk_sum = 0;
        for(int c : chalk){
            chalk_sum += c;
        }

        k %= chalk_sum;

        for(int i = 0; i < chalk.size(); i++){
            if(k < chalk[i]){
                return i;
            }
            k -= chalk[i];
        }
        return -1;
    }
};


Answers that contain only code are generally considered poor quality. You should explain how your code resolves the posted problem - as the accepted answer does. Also, the question is tagged "java", so C++ code may be confusing for people seeking a Java solution. I suggest that you, at least, [edit] your answer and indicate that the code is C++.
